# Best way to migrate Content from drupal 6 to 7?

Tags: 7, upgrading

Becoming more familiar with Drupal by doing a drupal 6 to 7 upgrade along with switching Ubercart to Commerce.  But the site just doesnt seem to work right.

I followed the upgrade procedure suggested by drupal but something is off

Having random errors all over the place, admins running into php memory limit errors(ex. people > permissions), missing fields, unable to add criteria to views.

Is there a better way to do this. Should I start with a fresh install and import programatically someway or with a a module?

Its a fair amount of content i have to import but would it be better just to do it manually?

Im just wondering how others go about doing this because there seem to be mixed opinions

Comment: Which modules are you using? Any custom ones? How many nodes/comments does your site have? More details about your current installation and setup will help others to understand better your problem.

Comment: You should be using Migrate.
Leaving for someone else to post a more detailed explanation as an answer.

Comment: @BojanZivanovic it's years later and no one posted answer, so I did. But if you will finally find a time ;) I'll delete it - I don't want to steal your rep ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) might be the module you need:

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly recommended).

There is specialized [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) for just the task you need:

> migrate_d2d provides a framework based on the Migrate API for migrating content from Drupal 5, Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 sites into the Drupal 7 site where it is installed. As of the 2.1 release, It requires Migrate 2.6 or later. Besides addressing contemporary needs to migrate to Drupal 7, it has helped serve as a proof-of-concept for incorporating the migration approach into core as an upgrade path (https://groups.drupal.org/imp).

It's far from perfect, all right, but it's good and well tested - in my experience it is most solid way unless you want to write custom one just for your case.

Answer (score 0):

This module can help you: http://drupal.org/project/upgrade_status, it has a very useful submodule 'upgrade_assist".

Details from its project page:

> The Upgrade Status module checks the list of projects you have installed and shows their availability for the new version of Drupal core, which can be one of the following:
>
> - Available: A stable release of this project is available.
> - In development: A development release of this project is available, which can be installed for testing purposes.
> - Not ported yet: There are no releases available for this project.
>
> Clicking on any of the modules' boxes will show you notes about upgrading the project, as well as a link to download the new version.